# SqlServer 2019 using table and scalar function into cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, cursor, scalar

I occurred a strange error:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
>
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill
>   state.

It seems that error is generated when I use a cursor like :

```
DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR
            FOR 
                SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM dbo.fn_Table('n:',dbo.[fn_Scalar](var)) ORDER BY VAL) 
                from table
```

If I taken the select to run it, it is ok.

If in cursor I execute only fn_Table OR fn_Scalar, it is ok.

If in cursor I execute BOTH functions, I have the above error.

In older versions of SQL server (than 2019) the cursor is running properly.

Could you, please, give me an idea?

Thank you.

L.E.
The functions are:
ALTER function [dbo].[UrlDecode](@url nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
as 
begin
    declare @foo datetime=getdate();

DECLARE @Position INT,
        @Base CHAR(16),
        @High TINYINT,
        @Low TINYINT,
        @Pattern CHAR(21)

```
SELECT  @Base = '0123456789abcdef',
    @Pattern = '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%',
    @URL = REPLACE(@URL, '+', ' '),
    @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

WHILE @Position > 0
    SELECT  @High = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 1, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
        @Low = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 2, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
        @URL = STUFF(@URL, @Position, 3, CHAR(16 * @High + @Low - 17)),
        @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

RETURN  @URL
```

end

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep VARCHAR(32), @s VARCHAR(MAX))

RETURNS @t TABLE
    (
        val VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

AS
BEGIN

```
--declare @foo datetime=getdate();
--Remove separator if the case
IF RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@s)),1) = @sep 
    SET @s = LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@s)), LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@s))) - 1);

DECLARE @xml XML
SET @XML = N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(@s, @sep, '</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

INSERT INTO @t(val)
SELECT r.value('.','VARCHAR(250)') as Item
FROM @xml.nodes('//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)

RETURN
```

END

And the cursor is:
DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR
FOR 
select (SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM dbo.split('n:',dbo.UrlDecode) ORDER BY VAL) from  ABSENTEE

OPEN cursor_product;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product
END;
```

CLOSE cursor_product;
DEALLOCATE cursor_product;

Please, ignore how is defined the cursor, the error occours, anyway.
Thank you.

Comment: add a foo statement anywhere in fn_Scalar() : declare @foo datetime=getdate();   execute your statement. If it works, read about scalar udf inlining in sql2019

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the suggestion. As I said, the functions are working if are not used together into a cursor.

Comment: Do you have related messages in the SQL Server error log, such as a dump? If so, apply the latest CU if you haven't already done so.

Comment: I have the files, and I don't understand nothing from them. I installed the last updates from sql server.

Comment: Have you tried lptr suggestion ?, he told you to add a "declare @foo datetime=getdate()", to your function.He explained to you that the reason was because the scalar udf inlining added in SQL Server 2019, and to search for more information about it. This feature is an optimization of the execution of the function, if you add a variable declaration, you are disabling this new optimization, so it will be executed unoptimized, as they were executed on SQL Servers prior 2019.

Comment: I added and the same error. I'll read about scalar UDF inlining.. But, again, the cursor was fine in earlier versions of the SQL server...

Comment: This has a bad code smell to it. You have a cursor which inside calls a table valued function and one of those parameters is a scalar function. The way to solve this would be to unravel all this and use a proper query. Why do you need a cursor in the first place? My guess is you don't.

Comment: At the very least you need to provide a [mcve] or anybody trying to help is just guessing.

Comment: I added the functions and the cursor. The table absentee can be any table. I corrected the script, but I need to understand WHY happened the error, in order to avoid another bugs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If the select alone runs well, I propose you to retrieve your data first into a table variable, so you can iterate it later, once the calls to your function are finished, avoiding any kind of weird locking between those calls.

```
DECLARE @MyData table (VAL int)

INSERT INTO @MyData (VAL)
       SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM dbo.fn_Table('n:',dbo.[fn_Scalar](var)) ORDER BY VAL) 
       FROM table

DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT VAL FROM @MyData
```

Comment: It is a old functionality and this kind combination (2 functions into a cursor) exists in many places. I need to know if I can change something in Sql server option in order to run the scripts.

Comment: You can try @lptr suggestion. I have explained it a little more for you.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you'll have to change the cursor's select statement (scalar udf-inlining was just a blind guess [function+sql2019 not working, but works pre-sql2019] , the problem is the cursor's execution) :

Option 1:

```
The answer of Marc Guillot (populate a table and iterate over that)
```

Option 2: APPLY( function calls)

```
DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR FOR 
select f.VAL
from ABSENTEE as a
cross /*outer ?*/ apply
(
    SELECT TOP 1 VAL 
    FROM dbo.split('n:',dbo.UrlDecode(a.columnXYZ)) 
    ORDER BY VAL
) as f;
```

Option 3: aggregation on ABSENTEE table

```
DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR FOR 
select (SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM dbo.split('n:',dbo.UrlDecode(columnXYZ)) ORDER BY VAL) 
from ABSENTEE
group by ABSENTEE.columnXYZ, ABSENTEE.othercolumn(s)
```

Option 4: windowed aggregation on the function's result

```
DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR FOR 
select 
    MIN(
          (SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM dbo.split('n:',dbo.UrlDecode(columnXYZ)) ORDER BY VAL) 
       ) over(partition by columnXYZ)
from ABSENTEE
```

Comment: I need to understand: could you, please, tell why the function is not the correct one? I tried with CREATE FUNCTION fn_Table ( at id NVARCHAR(MAX))RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN ( SELECT at id as val) and the cursor worked

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the functions. SQL2019 crashes when trying to execute the cursor. Check the sql error log: " SQL Server is terminating this session. Contact Product Support Services with the dump produced in the log directory.". You might want to report it as a bug:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server